insert custom tag in the head for each specific page
I'm using joomla4, I would like to insert the schema.org json code in the head of some specific pages, do you know if it's possible to do it with some modification or override?
Thanks

Did you get this sorted ok? I think that you could do this via a system plugin, eg listening for onBeforeCompileHead (https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onBeforeCompileHead) and then getting the Document class and calling setMetaData (https://api.joomla.org/cms-4/classes/Joomla-CMS-Document-Document.html#method_setMetaData). You can use the Document instance or Joomla Input (https://manual.joomla.org/docs/general-concepts/input) to work out if you're on a page you want to modify.
